# Matrix multiply a list of Matrices in Keras

Tags: python, keras, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to add my own defined layer in Keras. In the layer I wanted to multiply a matrix with size (30, 20) with the input which is a list of matrices with size (?, 20, 40). The "?" depends on the input batch size.

I want to have (30, 20) * (?, 20, 40) -> (?, 30, 40).

I tried to use K.dot() and K.dot_batch() but they didn't work. Is there a way to do this in Keras?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd better give the code of your defined layers.

Comment: Is the (30, 20) matrix a weight of your layer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the (30, 20) matrix is a weight of the layer, and you want to calculate the dot product for each of the 40 matrices. 
I.e. Letting `X` be (?, 20, 40)-tensor, and `W` be (30, 20)-matrix,
`Y[:, :, k] = Dot(X[:, :, k], W)` (with proper transposing for size compatibility).

If this is what you do, you can implement that by combining [Permute](https://keras.io/layers/core/#permute) and [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed).

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Permute, TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Model

x = Input((20, 40))
y = Permute((2,1))(x)
y = TimeDistributed(Dense(30))(y)
y = Permute((2,1))(y)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
model.summary()
```

yields:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_13 (InputLayer)        (None, 20, 40)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
permute_15 (Permute)         (None, 40, 20)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_9 (TimeDist (None, 40, 30)            630       
_________________________________________________________________
permute_16 (Permute)         (None, 30, 40)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 630
Trainable params: 630
Non-trainable params: 0
```

If you still need to implement a custom layer, a good reference will be `TimeDistributed` source code (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/wrappers.py#L114).

Sketch of the approach will be:

1. permute to (n, 40, 20)
2. flatten to (n*40, 20) dimension
3. take the dot product -> (n*40, 30)
4. reshape back to (n, 40, 30)
5. permute to (n, 30, 40)

Comment: how about left side mat mul?